# Can SwapChainBackgroundPanel be added as a sub control?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, xna-4.0, windows-8.1, monogame

I created a sample app with mono wizard "MonoGame Windows Store(XAML) Project".

it created page GamePage.xaml

```
<SwapChainBackgroundPanel
    x:Class="Mono.GamePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Mono"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="LightGray">
            <Button Content="Stop" x:Name="btnStartStop" Click="btnStartStop_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</SwapChainBackgroundPanel>
```

However, I want to add this SwapChainBackgroundPanel into another xaml page (example BlankPage.xaml).

But, when I run the app. it report an exception
WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type 'GamePage' to a collection of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UIElementCollection'.

So, Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this? and How can I do this? I want to add SwapChainBackgroundPanel as a sub control of other page.

Answer (score 0):

Can SwapChainPanel be added as a sub-control (your question) == yes.

Can sub-controls be added to a SwapChainPanel? (your code) == no.